# conditionally load different reducers into redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a function that check the role of a user. I want to base on that pass different reducer into a store, is that possible?

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { getUserRole } from './utils'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

import userReducers from './reducers'
import adminReducers from './reducers/admin'

//share reducer btw member and admin
let reducers
if (getUserRole() === 'member') {
  reducers = userReducers
} else {
  reducers = adminReducers
}

console.log('reducers', reducers) //undefined unless I refresh the page

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
)
export default store
```

I found a problem, `reducers` is undefined for the first time (like I login) unless I refresh it.

Comment: What do you see when you try `console.log(userReducers)` and  `console.log(adminReducers)`?

Comment: Rather than doing the conditional check in your root component, can't you run getUserRole() in a child component and dispatch separate actions based on the role, which in turn call different reducers?

Comment: @VijayMenon userReducer is a combined reducer, it has so many things. And there is no need to load admin reducer when a non admin is logged in.

Comment: @Jackson it's a combined reducers of user and admin

Comment: Can you add the adminReducer functions in the userReducer itself and call them based on the actions being dispatched when getUserRole() runs and the role is returned?

Comment: If you have to do it logically this way, I saw multiple resources for dynamically loading reducers. Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/qk3n9xmm3w  
                        Documentation-    https://tylergaw.com/articles/dynamic-redux-reducers/